# C# string SavePath С новым именем

Tags: c#, изображения

Как добавить к каждой сохранённой картинке к примеру дату и время ?

```
private void button5_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            var res1 = (Bitmap)pictureBox1.Image;
            var res2 = ConvertTextToImage(textBox1.Text, "Bookman Old Style", 10, Color.White, Color.Black, 100, 100);

            string SavePath = @"c:\\QR\\image.JPG";

            Merge(res1, res2).Save(SavePath);
        }
```

Comment: Смотря как должно преобразоваться. В общем случае используете `Path.GetDirectoryName`, `Path.GetFileName` и `Path.GetExtension`, а затем обратно собираете по кусочкам через `$"{directory}{filename}{extension}"` - подставите по вкусу что вам надо из текущей даты/времени. Оф. документация где-то тут: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: `string SavePath = $@"c:\QR\image_{DateTime.Now}.JPG";` Обратите внимание, если используете символ `@` перед строкой, экранировать слеш вторым слешом не нужно.

Comment: Так так же и будет image_{DateTime.Now}.JPG сохраняться

Comment: @ПавелРоманов Знак `$` обозначает интерполяцию строк - выражение в фигурных скобках "вставляется" в строковый литерал: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/string-interpolation. Правда не помню с какой версии языка их можно вместе с `@` использовать, поэтому у вас теоретически может и не сработать, но  в этом случае должна выдаваться ошибка компиляции.

Comment: Таки да возникает ошибка при сборке Изначально это исключение было создано в этом стеке вызовов: 
    [Внешний код]
    qr_code.Form1.button5_Click_1(object, System.EventArgs) в Form1.cs
    [Внешний код]
    qr_code.Program.Main() в Program.cs

Comment: Точно при сборке? Пишет про стек вызовов.

Comment: При отладке приложения

Comment: Тогда приведите текст исключения, из того что выше понятно лишь что оно в методе `button5_Click_1`

Comment: Вызвано исключение: "System.NotSupportedException" в mscorlib.dll
Необработанное исключение типа "System.NotSupportedException" в mscorlib.dll
Данный формат пути не поддерживается.

Comment: Возможно это из-за стандартного формата `ToString` для даты, в любом случае правильнее будет делать как советует @AK.

Comment: @SmorcIRL Напиши свою почту

Comment: Если у вас есть вопросы, задавайте лучше здесь

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как-то так:

```
    private static string CreateFilename(string defaultpath, string dateformat)
    {
        string dir = Path.GetDirectoryName(defaultpath);
        string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(defaultpath);
        string date = DateTime.Now.ToString(dateformat);
        string ext = Path.GetExtension(defaultpath);

        return $"{dir}{name}{date}{ext}";
    }

    string SavePath = CreateFileName(@"c:\QR\image.JPG", "-dd_mm_yyyy-hh_mm_ss");
```

Comment: Ок т.е в button5_Click_1 добавляется только вышеуказанный кусочек?

Comment: Зависит от того нужен постоянен ли у вас формат шаблонного пути или нет. Мне кажется вы хотели сохранять файл с выбором пути из диалога. Лучше будет этот код вынести в отдельный метод, исходя из выбранного вами шаблона.

Comment: Я пробовал  using (SaveFileDialog dialog = new SaveFileDialog())  в теме где вы мне отвечали выше. Диалог для сохранения появляется но не сохраняет при указании пути.

Comment: @ПавелРоманов зачем вы тогда отметили ответ как решение и создали ещё один вопрос на эту же тему? Давайте вы попробуете разобраться сами с учетом данных ответов, и только в крайнем случае задавать новые вопросы.